# SQL: How can I sort strings in Date format(MONTH/DD/YY)?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sorting, date

I have a table Exams, where I have a date column in the following format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

I have to sort this column and change the format to 'MONTH/DD/YYYY'

My code is the following:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(Exam_Date, 'MONTH/DD/YY') AS Exam_date
FROM 
    Exams
WHERE 
    Student_id = '0000049'
ORDER BY 
    Exam_date ASC
```

Unfortunately this sorts my column like a string :(

I also have tried this:

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(Exam_date, 'MONTH/DD/YYYY'), 'MONTH/DD/YYYY') AS Exam_date
FROM Exams
WHERE Student_id = '0000049'
ORDER BY Exam_date
```

Here I got them sorted but in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format :/

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQL Server?   TO_CHAR isn't valid syntax in any version I've heard of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using sql server. It appears you are using Oracle. If you were using Sql Server, you could just cast to datetime, like the following:

```
ORDER BY cast(Exam_date as DATETIME)
```

I haven't used Oracle for a very long time... try using the following:

```
ORDER BY TO_DATE(Exam_Date)
```

Comment: oh thank you, it's ok if i put ORDER BY cast(Exam_date as date)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm using oracle, sorry for incorrect information, and thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

I'm making the assumption that your underlying field in the Exams table for Exam_date is a date or datetime type. If so, you need to understand that when you perform manipulations on a field and then call that expression the same thing as the underlying field name, you lose access to the base field when you attempt to do the ORDER BY.

A better approach would be to expose the expression as a different field name. If you cannot do that, you would want to expose your base field as an aliased one so that you can sort by it.

A second assumption that I'm making is that the TO_CHAR is a custom function you implemented to display the date as text.

Method 1:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Exam_Date, 'MONTH/DD/YY') AS Exam_date_Text
FROM Exams
WHERE Student_id='0000049'
ORDER BY Exam_date ASC
```

Method 2:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Exam_Date, 'MONTH/DD/YY') AS Exam_date, Exam_date AS ORIG_Exam_date
FROM Exams
WHERE Student_id='0000049'
ORDER BY ORIG_Exam_date ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I understood how this works

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(Exam_Date,'MONTH/DD/YYYY') Exam_date2
from Exams 
order by Exam_Date;
```

Your code fails because you aliased as a same column name so it's ordering by  Exam_date as string.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use a table alias to identify that the reference is to a column.  The only change is to the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY Exams.Exam_date ASC
```

Comment: Curious that this would be downvoted, since it seems like the best answer to the question.